# variation norm of a Fourier transform

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Motivated by certain uniform estimate in oscillatory integrals, I am now trying to calculate the Fourier transform of the function ${\large e^{i|t|^{\epsilon}}/t}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where $\epsilon\in (0,1)$.Ultimately, I would like to prove that the Fourier transform of the above function has bounded $r$-variation for some $r<2$.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to have bounded $r$-variation if $\sup_{\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}}(\sum_{i}|f(a_{i+1})-f(a_i)|^r)^{1/r}<\infty$, where $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ denotes an increasing sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is someone aware of any literature concerning the variation norm of the Fourier transform of this kind? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the FT of this function? (It is not locally integrable and thus doesn't define a distribution in an obvious way.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling The Fourier transform is defined in the principle value sense, like how we define the Fourier transform of the Hilbert kernel $1/t$. Hence near $t=0$, there is no problem. Near $t=\infty$, there will be high oscillation either from $e^{i|t|^{\epsilon}}$ or from $e^{-it\xi}$ to make up the fact that $1/t$ is not integrable.